# (Soft) What maths should I concentrate on at 16-18 years old?

Tags: soft-question

Some background information first of all:
I'm 16 now and just started studying mathematics intensely. I live in the UK and my goal is to eventually become very good at advanced mathematics (graduate level and up) but that is still far in the future. I'm about a year or slightly more ahead from the expected curriculum knowledge in my age group.

The advice I'm seeking of is that I am not sure whether to keep going ahead of the curriculum and eventually learning university maths a year before actually going to uni or should I try to improve my problem solving skills by for example trying out Mathematical Olympiad questions. If I do MO instead then I fear I might be wasting time (even if I'm improving at problem solving) when all I really want to do is the more advanced stuff which is more proof laden I hear anyway.

To answer the question it might be helpful to know what my intentions for pursuing mathematics are. I enjoy learning new fields of mathematics that I did not know of before. A new topic excites me, a new problem to solve with the same tools just doesn't have the same effect on me mentally. I can pick up stuff quiet quickly and get bored if I'm forced to keep doing what I already know without any new knowledge. I realise however that mathematical ability is not just about knowledge but also problem solving skill.

Comment: I highly highly recommend you start learning abstract algebra.  Try to find a relatively easy introduction.

Comment: I recommend you start learning some linear algebra and real analysis. but you need to know a little of calculus

Comment: As @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez said. :|

Comment: It might also be a good idea to start learning how to make formal proofs.  Books such as Velleman's *How to Prove It* and Polya's *How to Solve It* could help in that regard.

Comment: From personal experience, "I already know part of the curriculum" on its own is not enough to get in Cambridge. Learn all the maths you can, but make sure it is not to the detriment of the other school subjects you're studying. Past that, I agree with the comments above.

Comment: I recommend finding part of the subject that you really like and following that. Different folks are motivated and have aptitude for different things. I like convex analysis and find abstract algebra almost impenetrable.

Comment: I recommend abstract algebra, together with elementary number theory.

Comment: BTW, where are you at in your studies right now?

Comment: @Bye_World I don't recommend that tbh. Just reading Analysis/LA books should be enough to teach one how to write proofs.

Comment: @HasanSaad I would think analysis might be a bit much to expect if OP is still studying high school geometry or something -- (s)he hasn't responded yet with what (s)he has already learned.  On the other hand it doesn't take much to start learning proofs.  But then it really just has to do with with parts of math OP is most interested in.

Comment: Well, it worked for me after I read Apostol's calculus on my own. I thought it'd work for OP too.

Comment: IMPA books are from high-level.  it will help you, try to learn some portuguesse too. http://www.impa.br/opencms/pt/publicacoes/projeto_euclides/index.html

Comment: @Bye_World I know nearly all the mathematics you are expected to learn before uni, in the coming months, I want to polish up on this knowledge before going on to harder stuff. What I'm getting from this post is that I should definitely plough through for more knowledge rather than doing some stuff like the Math Olympiad? Intuitively that's what I'd like to do anyway but just wondering if it would not be worth it.

Comment: @MarkK Math Olympiad books help you learn how to reason things out and teaches you a bunch of tricks for quickly solving certain classes of problems.  If you get really good at it and score highly on whatever the UK's equivalent of the Putnam exam is, then it could be very helpful in getting into good grad schools.  But as for helping you in your later career as a mathematician (assuming that's where you think you're headed), I think learning a diverse group of topics rather than a bunch of time-saving tricks would be more helpful.

Comment: It depends how you approach the Olympiad - if you read the coaching manuals that's one thing, but if you treat the papers as a useful source of difficult problems and work away at them until you can do them yourself, you learn problem solving and resilience. Aside from Geometry, which is not always taught well in the UK there is very little in there that you won't know.

Comment: For an overview, get hold of (borrow) a copy of the Princeton Companion to Mathematics - see what excites you there - that has follow-up suggestions for further reading too, and is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: It would be worth going through the Cambridge reading list at http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/admissions/readinglist.pdf ranging from popular and recreational mathematics to  readable textbooks.  But your priority at this stage should be the A level syllabus and harder approaches to it such as preparing for STEP (aimed at the top 5% of A level mathematicians) as described at http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/admissions/step/

Answer (score 4):

Basically, if you're just interested in what topics to learn next, you really could start on almost anything.  Your choices *roughly* come down to

- foundational math (set theory, logic, proofs)
- geometry
- linear algebra
- calculus/ real analysis (at the level of Spivak)
- abstract algebra
- number theory
- probability theory

Each has their benefits.  I'd suggest taking some time to research each one and trying to figure out which grabs your attention the most.  Then you can invest a more substantial amount of time and figure out if it really is someone you enjoy.  If not, you've definitely got time to change your mind.  The point though is to just find something you like and run with it.

Answer (score 3):

It would be  nice if you could learn some basics of **calculus**.
But be sure first that you are already good at the very basics of algebra, identities, logarithms etc.

Do not try Math Olympiad problems.
In my opinion, they train you to be a good "warrior" for 3 hours (the exam) but a mathematician is not a warrior and certainly has plenty of time. 
Try to understand the proofs you read and not only memorize the theorems.

Along with Calculus a good advice would be to study **Number Theory**.
This way you will see what mathematical genius actually is. *Trust me!*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do try to understand any new theorems I come across (proving them from scratch and so on) and I'm never happy with just memorising - I need to understand what's going on! I do like the look of Analysis (watched some Real Analysis lectures) but the look of number theory scares me sometimes and sadly hasn't really grabbed my interest yet.

Comment: Number Theory scares us all at the beginning.Just relax and enjoy what you read.You will find your way in maths.You have all the time in the world.(Until you become a professor and realize that "all the time" will be "some time" everyday)

Comment: "Do not try Math Olympiad problems." This is _so wrong_! Math Olympiad problems are one of the best problem sets I know. The issue you describe is not with the _problems_, but how these are usually studied. You are right, practicing solely for contests promotes certain undesirable habits, but you can solve Math Olympiad problems at your leisure, taking days to solve one if you need it (esp. if it is hard).

Comment: @dtldarek This is your opinion.I disagree but it is impossible to know who or if someone is right.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas Sentence "Try to understand the proofs you read and not only memorize the theorems." suggests you think that in general doing MO problems will promote memorization over understanding. I've certainly met people like these, but there are others, perhaps you have just had bad experience? There is a significant difference between doing problems to get points (the more the better) and to understand what is really going on there (what causes the answer to be like that). There's more on this in one paragraph of my post.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend reading [Velleman's How to Prove it](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995), which teaches you about how to think logically and construct mathematical proofs. This is often the biggest hurdle for new mathematics students: figuring out what constitutes a proof, what are logically valid arguments, and how to present a proof.

Alongside Velleman, I would recommend [Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319110799). Linear algebra is the study of vector spaces (and later on, modules) and the linear transformations between them. Linear algebra plays a key role in every field of mathematics, as well as in physics and computer science. For example, the derivative operation in calculus is all about linearizing functions.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wasted. Hard problems which force you to think are always good. Cambridge University [has a reading list](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/admissions/readinglist.pdf) and there is more information [on the website](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/admissions/). And I guess other faculties will do something similar.

Answer (score 2):

My personal experience in the US is that there is a vast difference between the typical high school curriculum (algebra, calculus which are primarily learning methods) and what might be considered pure math.

The ability to prove things (as several others have mentioned) is paramount. This also entails recognizing what conditions are necessary and sufficient, where thins can fall apart, and a wonderful exercise in self-reflection to consider if you really know what you are doing.

That said, I feel (once you have a familiarity with calculus, also mentioned above) that you persue a particular course. Many programs begin with real analysis. The benefit of this is that math knowlegde is often cumulative, and thus following a course will have the added benefit of seeing how and where prior developed material comes into play.

This is quite different from a non-math or science program, as you can read any Shakespearian play or Wordsworth poem without any prior experience.

If you are interested, here is a link to a free down-load of a RA course given by Vaughan Jones (Fields Medal). They are self-contained meaning they start at the beginning, and you need not look elsewhere as you progress. (Notice however the first few pages are a bit technical for thoroughness, so take a glance, and start a page 4.) There is nothing like the real thing.

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxtYXRoMTA0c3AyMDExfGd4OjJiNTJkM2M2ZWUzZGIwYWQ

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, where you are from (EDIT: okay... I do, nevermind). This kind of matters, because education differs between different countries (at least I know, here in Germany it is different from math at American universities). The most difficult step is going from the "pre-rigorous" to the "rigorous" state. In Germany this is more important, because rigor starts with the first year in university. I believe it is different in America, where one learns "Calculus" before "Real Analysis" and "Linear Algebra" means matrix arithmetic, not "theory of finite-dimensional vector spaces".  In Germany for example, there is no "calculus", we start with "real analysis" immediately. However, at some point or another you have to make the transition from understanding things only by intuition to proving things. The best advice I can give you:

Practice, practice, practice!

More specifically, I personally benefited by learning some of this stuff first:

- propositional logic, meaning of quantifiers
- (naive) set theory, including membership, subsets, union, intersection, Cartesian products, relations, orderings, equivalence relations and quotient sets, functions, tupels,
- mathematical induction

...and from here you can go anywhere! Well, starting with abstract algebra (groups or vector spaces) is a good idea, in my opinion. If you prefer it, do analysis (just know, that proofs in analysis tend to be "messy and complicated")

Comment: "I live in the UK"

Comment: It could take a year or more to go through a couple of books on logic and set theory.  I don't think putting off the *fun* math to learn these foundational topics will do anything but put OP off mathematics.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM good point ;)

Comment: @Bye_World we had about 3 weeks to take in these things, and then we  continued with the axioms of the reals on the one hand and with the vector space axioms on the other hand . I was really glad, this stuff wasn't new to me....

Comment: Well I'd at least suggest doing something more fun -- like linear algebra or number theory -- concurrently with those foundational books then.  Because while there are some people who really enjoy foundational math, it's definitely a minority.

Comment: @Bye_World mmh... maybe I just can't imagine doing either of those things without any clue about sets etc., or especially induction in number theory. it might just be close minded, true.

Comment: Generally you learn bits of naive set theory and propositional logic as you go.  Every elementary number theory book I've seen includes a section on induction, for instance.  You don't need an entire book to teach you the basics.  I'm not saying *eventually* OP shouldn't come back and study these more in depth, I just think that at $16$ he's at a critical stage where if he gets frustrated/ disappointed about mathematics he might just give up on it.

Comment: @Bye_World Okay, ... I didn't suggest that. I didn't think of reading particular (especially whole) books --- of course you're right.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a somewhat similar situation('discovered' math in mid-end of HS, thinking about going into competitions or directly to uni level math) and I choose the latter option. I would suggest that before doing anything else you should get your hands in an "advanced" calculus text to learn what a proof should look like(e.g. Apostol's or Spivak's for a gentler introduction) and learn some logic/set theory with something like Halmo's Naive Set Theory since both are used *everywhere*.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

At this stage all you need to care about is to *keep stretching your brain* in many different directions. There still will be *a lot* of time for you to learn all the amazing theories, useful tools or amusing curiosities. Let your imagination run free and *enjoy* the math you do (but be serious, don't slack off).

If I were to give you one advice on what to do: *experiment*!

---

**Disclaimer**

Each mathematician has his/her own best set of things to do and these differ considerably. I have no idea what *will* work best for you, I can only suspect and even that is warped by my own subjective perspective. Of course, I have some observations about what worked and what did not for my friends or students I taught, on this observations and various musings of others I based the advice that follows. However, you won't really know what works until you try it - each to his own.

**General advice**

If you had to choose between knowledge and thinking, at this stage I urge you to pick thinking.

Both are important, but there is only a finite amount of time you can spend on them and

- you will pick up some knowledge along the way and that will be enough to prepare yourself for more knowledge in the future,
- you will be able to learn new things for many, many, many years,
- there are some quite good substitutes for knowledge (e.g. books, internet),
- I know no conclusive research on this topic, but to me it seems that thinking capabilities work similarly to other human traits, that is, the early years determine the limits you can later achieve (the cap on your abilities).

It doesn't really matter that much what kind of math do you do, as long as you keep stretching your brain in different directions. Also, whatever you do, be serious, don't slack off.

**More personal advice**

Personally, I would advise you against learning advanced material and study university topics ahead of time (more on this below). Instead, practice *a lot* of Math Olympiad problems, but optimize for brain-stretching, not for contests (more on this also below).

Another thing that would be great to do is to experiment with math. Take some math and use it, or find some practical (getting purely abstract too soon won't do you any good) problem (it might small and insignificant, doesn't matter) you would like to solve and try to do it with math (perhaps learn some new things in the process).

I will not only give you an example, but three *tasks* that will be great for your thinking (they will take some time, but not that much):

1. Make a simulation of a lunar lander (the graphics can be trash) according to physics equations, including (at least) mass, gravity, atmosphere density (to have some damping effects) and thrust forces from engines. Represent them as differential equations and solve numerically (use something simple like [Verlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration)).
2. Transform an audio voice recording (e.g. some MP3) using your own [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithm (it can be DFT, doesn't matter), e.g. to be a bit higher. (To convert the numeric data to and from audio files use some tool or library.)
3. Code a minimal [raytracer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_%28graphics%29). Try to use [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) inside and Monte Carlo methods during rendering. Also, play with [transformation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

If these sound intimidating, don't worry, they are much easier than they seem and you can find a lot of help online (tutorials, forums, stack-exchange sites, etc.). Besides, you don't need to understand all the details of the underlying theories, to complete these tasks you only need to learn a few bits for each (e.g. derivatives and integrals, complex numbers and polynomial evaluation, matrix multiplication and some randomization). In fact, a few paragraphs below I will argue that you should *not* learn too much advanced material too early.

The above tasks require some programming skills, but I guarantee that coding ability will be useful to you (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132042/26306)). Each has an underlying topic (differential equations, FFT, linear algebra) which is highly relevant, frequently used in applied math and amazing by itself. You will have a better understanding of what math can do, and believe me, doing it personally is a whole other experience than just hearing about it. Finally, it is great fun seeing it run!

(If you are more focused on abstract math, these problems will still be helpful.)

**On rediscovering the wheel**

Whatever you will ultimately do, at your age, don't be afraid of rediscovering the wheel. Although in research it's better to rely on known theorems rather than prove everything from scratch (human lifespan is limited), there is no better way of learning how to invent new things (I would recommend against true open-ended research, because it's easy to get frustrated).

Basically all standard textbook problems rediscover the wheel (they were solved before, weren't they?), but somehow we understand that this is precisely their intention. However, ordinary theorems or folklore facts can also be though of as challenges. This is standard in geometry, so why not in other areas? For example, could you solve the quadratic equation without knowing/using the exact formula for roots?

**On university curriculum**

I have nothing but anecdotal data to support this claim, but I think that studying advanced books too early may not be such a good idea. You can find a more detailed description of my worries here: [Effects of early study of advanced books](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/7718/42), but to briefly summarize main points:

- such approach favors knowledge over thinking,
- when you study on your own, you might miss some important pieces,
- you train yourself in following the beaten track (rather than creating your own).

**On Math Olympiads**

Math Olympiad problems are one of the best mind stretchers I know. If you approach them right, a lot of them (depends on country) become great tryouts for your out-of-the-box thinking.

The most important thing here is not to optimize to get far in the contests, but to expand your mind. For example, there is a certain set of mathematical theorems which with enough practice allow you to solve many olympiad problems with little or no insight (e.g. the [Muirhead's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality) is notorious for killing fun). So when you spot a problem that is easily solvable by some "overpowered" theorem, either try to find another solution or go on to next problem. Similarly, do not measure your time when solving Math Olympiad problems. If you are stuck, *try harder* (rather than moving on or reading solution). If you can't stand the problem anymore, leave it and perhaps try again next week.

**Conclusion**

Don't just learn math, or as Paul R. Halmos have said: *Don't just read it; fight it!* (the picture comes from the [Abstruse Goose](http://www.abstrusegoose.com/) webcomic).

[image: How to study math]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: If I spend most of my time doing MO aren't I wasting my time learning methods I'll almost never use later on (except maybe in number theory). I hear advanced mathematics is more proof laden anyway which MO will barely help with. You say to enjoy the maths that I do and this is exactly why I want to go on to uni maths - I will enjoy the new maths much more than Olympiad questions or the projects you suggested. Why not just go on to harder material and chewing over some Olynpiad questions for fun from time to time?

Comment: @MarkK 1. If you do not enjoy MO problems, then forget it and do whatever else you feel better about. 2. Many MO problems are about proofs and for anything you wanted to learn instead, there still will be a time for you to learn it. 3. "Why not just go on to harder material" To be a mathematician you have to _produce new math_ - even if you were to learn all the great theories and all the useful techniques, you won't be any good if you don't produce anything. 4. It's not enouh to be able to do something, you have to be _efficient_ at it, that is, you should practice using and producing math.

Comment: I was able to identify all of the things on the dragon except for three! the belly, is that the Jacobi identity? And the two lowermost series, I can't really read them. Can you explain what is meant by "fighting" though?

Comment: @GPerez The belly is probably the first Bianchi identity (which follows from Jacobi identity). As for fighting, I think that P. Halmos urges us to be deeply (personally) engaged, as if our life was on the line, to be active instead of passive, to have a kind of intensity which is impossible when you "just read" math.

Comment: BTW, the longer quote goes like this: Don't just read it; fight it! Ask your own questions, look for your own examples, discover your own proofs. Is the hypothesis necessary? Is the converse true? What happens in the classical special case? What about the degenerate cases? Where does the proof use the hypothesis?

Comment: @dtldarek: Excellent answer. Except rediscovering the wheel in own way (and  practicing math Olympiad questions), do you have any other suggestion for expanding the thinking horizon (and to gain insights) ?

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar Thank you. Not really, in particular my own (both current and past) mind-stretching habits and exercises would be a terrible advice.

Comment: @dtldarek: This may be an off topic query, but I am curious to know why ?

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar If you are not careful, math can ruin your life and there are far more important things in life than mathematics. (I know it sounds banal.)

Comment: +1, This is a brilliant answer. I, being in almost the same situation of OP, have few questions: (i) Some of the olympiad problems are really good, but often I see a typical answer runs like: "*Use Kologorov's theorem, then apply Nogoloho inequality, and then finally apply the proof of well known Golono's problem, and this makes the problem trivial*".Having very bad experience of completely fooling myself by reading math textbook, I have stopped reading them - I just (plan to) work on interesting problem to derive the necessary math. But seeing this type of answers, it seems to me that (contd)

Comment: it's kinda impossible to derive the solution to such kind of contest problems in the fixed time. Is my assumption actually true, or is it possible to find some elegant-from-the-scratch solution to almost all comp. problems if I persist enough ?(ii) As I don't read any math book, the Algebra and Number Theory portions seems completely dry and motivation-less. Can you suggest some good book which develops (and/or encourages the reader to develop) algebra/number theory from scratch with proper motivation ?(iii) It's impossible for me to get any math tutor, but my proofs are actually super (contd)

Comment: nonsense, and don't make sense. How can I improve my proof writing ? Participating in online math forums like AOPS is probably the only good suggestion I got for this questions.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo Assuming all answers in that book are similar, I would not use it (unless it is the only thing I can access). I'm not sure what kind of problems do you train on, even today each country has its own standards, math folklore, etc. In my case it was certainly possible to solve all high-school olimpiad problems I've tried from scratch, but some needed lots of time (way more than what the contest limit is). That bar was raised much more when I became university student (i.e. I failed many, many times), but this is alright (e.g. some problems were from published papers). **Cont.**

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo **Cont.** One thing that helped me a lot was, when analyzing a solution to a problem I could not solve, that I compared it to my own (multiple) approaches to find where they were wrong/insufficient/not deep enough. At first my reaction was mostly WTF?!, but I've managed to train my intuition to get this feeling "there is yet another dependency right here that I cannot pinpoint" and then going deeper in that area was often more fruitful than other methods. **Cont.**

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo **Cont.** Currently my research area is far from Algebra or Number Theory, so I cannot recommend any book myself, have you tried searching for recommendations? As for learning proof writing: get your proofs read and commented on (and then try to improve). And don't be discouraged by initial downvotes if they happen. My own proof writing is now much better than it was years ago, but some people still think it's unintelligible (and it's great, because thanks to their high standards it's easier for me to improve). Good luck! **Fin.**

Comment: @dtldarek Thanks a lot for the quick and helpful reply ! But I don't quite understand (i) (First comment) *"That bar..."* - (What's the "bar raising" actually ? Also, you were doing Olympiad-ish/Putnam-ish problems ?) (ii) (Second comment) What you meant in "*...that I compared...enough*" and what you meant by "*there is yet...pinpoint*". Regarding my type of book recommendation, I asked [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081501/good-math-books-to-discover-stuff-by-yourself), but I got no good algebra/number theory answers.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo The difficulty of "hard" problems. The author's solution to my failed approaches. It's hard to explain, I can give you an example: suppose that according to your current understanding of the problem you can change "input" with two degrees of freedom (a plane geometry problem says "let $X$ be an arbitrary point within circle $O$") and the "output" (say position of some other point $Y$) also changes with two degrees of freedom, but then somehow it happens that it always belongs to some circle $I$ (only one degree of freedom); in such case you know you are missing something.

Comment: @dtldarek: Oh okay, now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo As for the books, I think you are being too picky. For example I remember Concrete Mathematics as a very good book (maybe not your style, but still). Also, I've never used guided discovery books, but they might actually be something that you are looking for. If you are reading a book, or even taking recommendations, you are being guided. Perhaps, if you don't want too many hints (which may come in the form of introductory problems), just skip them. If you are just searching for problems, you can always start [here](http://imomath.com/index.php?mod=23&options=other).