# Starting for Self Study of Mathematics

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I  am a Mathematics enthusiast but after High School i took a job. Now i want to do self study in mathematics and to dive deep into the subject. What should i do ? What books and articles should i read?

Comment: Get calculus text book!

Comment: What topics are you interested in particular?

Comment: I am in highschool. I was interested in a grad level course, so I searched for a suitable book and I started studying. That worked for me. Which topic are you interested in?

Comment: [This question's answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285186/soft-what-maths-should-i-concentrate-on-at-16-18-years-old/1285225#1285225) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691118809) would suit your purposes, since you mentioned that you would like to "dive deep into the subject"?

Comment: I recommend this book for you: http://smile.amazon.com/Basic-Mathematics-Serge-Lang/dp/0387967877/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1447854767&sr=1-2